# How to separate ViewController methods between X files

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've started to develop for iPhone just 1 week ago, things are going very well, but I don't know even how to ask this question (english is not my natural language), let`s see if you will understand me.

I have a ViewController that do many things. Show some images, do some animations, scroll the images while change the white dot from Page Controller...well, this kind of stuff.

But my ViewController.m have SO MUCH code for just 1 file. Well, **not YET**.

What I want to do is to create another files in which I could write moar code, improving readability and organization. Like this:

```
ViewController.m (ViewController general code)
ViewController_Navigation.m
ViewController_ImagesScrolling.m
ViewController_DBActions.m
```

With their respective header files, if needed.

So, any ideas or examples of how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The separation and encapsulation of function into separate classes is a common concept to break down masses of code. Methods that all have to do with one task can be lumped together as objects, usually UIView subclasses of some sort, or UIViewController subclasses for larger tasks that deserve their own screen of information. For example, you might have one that handles scrolling of images on its own once it's set up with the required UIImage's. Beyond that, however, you shouldn't generally split up a single controller's code. The controller contains all of the glue that holds the views it displays together along with the model in the MVC pattern. Thus, once all of the functionality that isn't reliant on the model has been sectioned off to views and you've partitioned the functionality into separate controllers in your interface, there is little you can do.

I would not recommend splitting the code into separate files because it all has one purpose: to coordinate what is going on on the screen and allow the views to interact with the model. However, what I usually do, is categorize and sort my code depending on what task it is managing. So, all of the life cycle and normal methods can go a the top, followed by all the table view methods, image viewer methods, etc.

This makes it easy to find code related to specific tasks, and even easier with the help of the `pragma` directive. Outside of any methods, in between your sorted groups of methods, you can use a `pragma mark` to assign an identifier to a location in your code, accessible through the jump bar, like I've done in the following example code.

```
#pragma mark - UIViewController Lifecycle Methods:

- (void) viewWillAppear{
    //stuff
};
- (void) loadView{
    //stuff
};

#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate & Datasource Methods:

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //stuff
 };
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //stuff
};
```

Now, if you were to go to the jump bar at the top of Xcode's code viewer and click on the right most object to find a method, you'd see this:

[image]

I don't believe that after sorting your code, marking it with pragma marks and separating all the code you can into other UIViews and UIViewControllers, you should feel the need to split your code into several files; you can just use the jump bar to go to any section of your code, effectively like swapping files would let you do. However, this way, you aren't fragmenting code from one class and leaving bits and pieces all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more objects/ controllers class for the single view/xib.

And each one of them will be assigned/linked to your class.

[image]

*-This is quite frequent design pattern in OSX, I hope this is even valid with ios.*

Answer (score 0):

iOS is based on the MVC model. Hence you should be using the controllers for managing the model and views.

Ideally I would be doing this:

a. Implement separate controllers for managing 
       1. Images -> separate the views for displaying images 
       2. Database 
       3. whatever else you have...

b. Implement a separate controller for managing the above controllers.

Comment: So, ideally a View cannot be controlled by 2+ controllers? I'm trying to get familiar with the MVC model...

Comment: @RicardoPieper That is right should be, especially if you are just starting out. Here is good conceptual link for MVC: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html